# Can't upload images to cloudsql database using SparkJava

Tags: java, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, spark-java

We have a database with 2 tables, users, and images. The users tables has 3 rows: password, username, and primary key. The images table has the image id, image, and the user tag(which equals the user primary key). When we try to upload an image the upload function doesn't return errors but when displaying the image there is an error:

> [qtp2073702330-26] INFO spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter - The requested route
>
> [/jpeg/getImagesTen] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept:
>
> [image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8]

We know that the error is mentioning the get Images route, but we know it's not the problem as when doing a simple query for everything in cloudsql (in our images table), not a single entry appears. So we know the upload function is flawed somehow, or cloudsql is not allowing our images.

The function we used to upload images looks like this:

```
public static String uploadImage(spark.Request request) {
    Context context = getSessionContext(request.session());
    String username = request.session().attribute("username");
    MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp");
    request.raw().setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.multipartConfig", multipartConfigElement);
    int userID = 0;
    try {
        System.out.println(username);
        String getUserID = "SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE Username = '" + username + "';";
        PreparedStatement getUserIDStatement = context.db.conn.prepareStatement(getUserID);
        ResultSet getUserRS = getUserIDStatement.executeQuery();
        while (getUserRS.next()) {
            System.out.println(getUserRS.getInt("UserID"));
            userID = getUserRS.getInt("UserID");
        }
        System.out.println(userID);
        System.out.println(request.raw().getPart("file"));
        Part filePart = request.raw().getPart("file");
        InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
        String sql = "INSERT images(Image, UserTag) VALUES (?,?);";
        PreparedStatement ps = db.conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setBinaryStream(1, fileContent);
        ps.setInt(2, userID);
        ps.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return "<!DOCTYPE html>"
            + "<html>\""
            + "<body background=\"https://webgradients.com/public/webgradients_png/019%20Malibu%20Beach.png\">"
            + "                <form method=\"get\" action=\"/\">\n"
            + "                    <button type=\"submit\">Go Back</button>\n"
            + "                </form>"
            + "</body>"
            + "</html>";
}
```

Here is the post route:

```
 post("/protected/upload", (req, res) -> uploadImage(req));
```

Here is the HTML form that submits the image:

```
<form method="post" action="/protected/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="file"/>
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Google Cloud SQL behaves, but from what I see in your code:

```
INSERT images(Image, UserTag) VALUES (?,?);
```

should probably read

```
INSERT INTO images(Image, UserTag) VALUES (?,?);
```

And you want to make sure that:

- Google Cloud SQL has auto-commit enabled
- You close all JDBC related objects to avoid resource leaks (`PreparedStatement`, `ResultSet`).